# 'Unable to open FTDI Deivce tried: 'Quad RS232-HS' and 'Quad RS232-HS A''

Tags: usb, serial-port, debugging

I have used ftdi drivers to connect to our test boards many times, using the same README file that was written by my colleague years ago. I have applied the same procedure for ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, 20.04 with no problem. But when I tried to do the same for ubuntu 22.04, it doesn't seem to work and I get this error message. (for the ocdf command which is an aliase `alias ocdf='sudo rmmod ftdi_sio; openocd64_ab_fpga -f ab_fpga.cfg'`)

```
Info : only one transport option; autoselect 'jtag'
Info : Aldebaran JTAG 15000 kHz
Warn : Unable to open FTDI Device tried: 'Quad RS232-HS' and 'Quad RS232-HS A'
Error: unable to open ftdi device: 2
Runtime Error: /opt/abocd/share/openocd/scripts/ab_fpga.cfg:39: 
in procedure 'script' 
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 58
in procedure 'init' called at file "/opt/abocd/share/openocd/scripts/ab_fpga.cfg", line 39
```

I tried re-installing libftdi1 and libftdi1-2 to no avail. This is the content of ab_fpga.cfg file.

```
telnet_port 4444
gdb_port 3333
gdb_memory_map enable
gdb_flash_program enable

interface ft2232
ft2232_device_desc "Quad RS232-HS A"
ft2232_layout usbjtag
ft2232_vid_pid 0x0403 0x6011
adapter_khz 15000


jtag newtap aldebaranv8 cpu -irlen 8 -ircapture 1 -irmask 0xff -expected-id 0xe0a7345f
target create aldebaranv8.cpu aldebaranv8 -endian big -chain-position aldebaranv8.cpu -variant lm3s
aldebaranv8.cpu configure -work-area-virt 0 -work-area-phys 0x10000000 -work-area-size 0x1000000 -work-area-backup 0
init
source /opt/abocd/share/openocd/scripts/sjtag_fpga.tcl
```

What can I try? maybe I'll try using lower version of libftdi (that were used for ubuntu 22.04).

Comment: Remove the device, run: `dmesg` and `udevadm monitor -u` in separate shell terminals. Plug in again, add output to the question with output of `lsusb -t`. This to check if get detected, what is its description and default driver.

Comment: @user.dz thanks for the good info. the big boad has been moved to another machine so I cannot try it right now, but when I have time, I'll try it.